# Consistency in Hilbert's Foundations of Geometry

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry, foundations, philosophy

After reading the entry in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy on Hilbert and Frege’s correspondence regarding the former’s *Foundations of Geometry*, I am quite puzzled by a claim that is made by the author of the article on page 7. There, she writes that the following pair of sentences is “demonstrably consistent in Hilbert’s sense”:

- Point B lies on a line between points A and C
- Point B does not lie on a line between points C and A

I have not yet had the chance to read Hilbert’s original work on this subject, but it seems implausible to me that these two statements would not entail a contradiction in his formal system. It would be greatly appreciated if someone can clarify whether I am in fact mistaken about this.

Comment: Why would this yield a contradiction? These are equivalent statements in Euclidian Geometry (in any reasonable background theory, e.g. ZF+C), and Hilbert's work was a minimalist axiomization of Euclidian Geometry...

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Well, that's an embarrassing error in my very first post on this site! The second assertion was a misquote and was intended to be "point B *does not* lie on a line between points C and A." I have edited the question accordingly. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the key points of the so-called [Frege-Hilbert controversy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-hilbert/#HilbFounGeom) was the use made by Hilbert of the method of "alternative interpretations" to prove consistency and independence results.

For Frege, a mathematical theory has a meaning: the intended interpretation, while for Hilbert a "formal system" must be developed without considering the intended interpretation.

> "The central idea of the alternative interpretation is that for Frege, the question whether a given thought is logically entailed by a collection of thoughts is sensitive not just to the formal structure of the sentences used to express those thoughts, but also to the contents of the simple (e.g., geometric) terms that appear in those sentences."

In a nutshell: if "between" is not read as *between*, and it is treated as a binary relation whatever, without further axioms we are not entitled to assert that the relation is *symmetric*.

In formal terms, $R(A,C,B)$ and $¬R(A,C,B)$ are contradictory, while $R(A,C,B)$ and $¬R(C,A,B)$ are not.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. What I find puzzling is how *any* interpretation of "lies between," whether standard or nonstandard, could simultaneously satisfy Euclid’s axioms as formalized by Hilbert, and the two sentences that I quoted above. I understand that, taken in isolation, $R(A, C, B) \land \neg R(C, A, B)$ need not be contradictory; however, since $R(A, C, B) \land R(C, A, B)$ can presumably be deduced from Euclid's axioms, how could any model of Euclidean geometry satisfy $R(A, C, B) \land \neg R(C, A, B)$? This is where I fail to see how these two sentences are consistent.

Comment: @MenanderI - yes, it can be deduced; see [Hilbert's axioms for Geometry: Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms#II._Order): the "symmetry" is an axiom (II.1).

Comment: What about an "alternative interpretation"? Not easy: ternary relations are not common ... But we may imagine something using "parental relations": the brother of thw wife is not the brother of the husband.

Comment: Perhaps the author’s comment about consistency was being made about relations in general? However, this is not what comes across in the article. That $R(A, C, B)$ and $\neg R(C, A, B)$ might be consistent for a generic relation $R$ is not the same as these being consistent when $R$ is the relation that appears in Hilbert’s axiomatization of Euclidean geometry, however it is ultimately interpreted in a model. Hence I don’t really see how this identifies a fundamental flaw in Hilbert’s consistency proof, which is what is claimed in the SEP article.

Comment: @MenanderI - why a "flaw in Hilbert’s consistency proof"? There is none... Hilbert's approach is to show (relative) consistency through a model: for Euclidean geometry a model based on reals (analytical geometry). The "alternative model" technique is needed for *independence*: the example on non-Euclidean geometries shows that the parallel postulate is independent from the remaining Euclid's axioms.Of course the *line* in the non-Euclidean plane is not what Euclid (and us) had in mind with "line" (but is nevertheless consistent with what Euclid's other axioms and definitions says about lines).

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood something that either Hilbert or Frege (or both) actually wrote. From the summaries that I have read, the consistency proof is entirely convincing and I do not personally see any flaws in it. But it sounds like Frege’s objection was that the model-theoretic consistency proof is illegitimate because Euclid’s theorems about “points” and “lines” on the one hand, and Hilbert’s reinterpretation of these in the real plane on the other hand, do not express the same “thoughts,” and consistency of one does not entail consistency of the other. A dubious argument in my view...